# Chart height area size increasing in C#

Tags: c#

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[t].Position.Y = 10;
Chart1.ChartAreas[t].Position.Height = 150;Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + t.ToString()].Position.Y = Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + (t - 1).ToString()].Position.Bottom;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + t.ToString()].Position.Height = 20;
```

I am getting error An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Can anyone help me to resolve the error.

Comment: So, what about that stack trace? :P Also, any inner exceptions? Also, which line is giving the code? What is the value of `t`?

Comment: where t used in for loop , where t ranges from zero to ten. there is hundreds of graphs I want to position the graph. but right now its shows all with no cleared. Chart1.ChartAreas[t].Position.Y = 10; giving error.

Comment: So if it `t` is 0 to 10, (t-1) actually gives a negative one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem due to positioning of chart area.at each time it will take same chart area.Here is a good example you can check:
[link](http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/align-multiple-chart-areas/)